# Correct closing tag in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here's a snippet of code I saw on the web and I'm wondering if the `<p/>`is a typo or what

```
 'config' : {

    'content' : $('#topGlobal')
  },

topGlobal.$content= topGlobal.config.content;

topGlobal.$sections = topGlobal.$content.
    find('ul.sections > li');

topGlobal.$side_nav = $('<p/>')
  .attr('id','side_nav ')
  .prependTo(topGlobal.$content);

topGlobal.$item_nav = $('<p/>')
  .attr('id','item_nav')
  .insertAfter(topGlobal.$side_nav);

...
```

The `<p/>`is repeated in several additional parts of this code.  This may sound like a stupid question and while I haven't tested it, I know `<p></p>` is correct HTML.  But because the author is very well respected JS author, I'm asking.  It's probably a typo, but I'd still like to know why the code is selecting the closing tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<p/>` is a shorthand you can use in jQuery to create a new HTML element instance.  In this case, a paragraph element.

Comment: Other possible notations are `<p>`, `<p />` and `<p></p>`. Adding an end tag doesn't really matter because the code is parsed by jQuery to dynamically create an HTML element out of it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`<p/>` is equivalent to `<p></p>` in HTML. It is not a closing tag, which would be `</p>`.