# Jquery selectors with <html-tag>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tags

I saw some jquery code with html-tag selector in an example I was looking at.

What does

```
var variable = '';    
$('<div />').text(variable).html()
```

means? I mean, I am curious about the `<div />` part as selector.
Can anyone explain that?

Edit: The HTML page doesn't have and divs inside.

Edit2: The full code is

```
<ul id="discussion"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
            + '</strong>:' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
</script>
```

When I render the page, I only see li tags inside the ul tag. No divs. That was my confusion. Is the `<div />` used for any html tag? I mean, I change it to `<a />` or `<p />` and it still works the same.

Sorry for not writing the question clearer the first time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct closing tag in jQuery selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040725/correct-closing-tag-in-jquery-selector)

Comment: Or are you asking why there's HTML in place of the selector? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: I have a lot of hate for the way jQuery overloads `$` to mean so many completely different things depending on what arguments you give it.

Comment: I updated the question, please see the last edit. I saw that question that @Quentin added to the question but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a div element but doesn't add it to the DOM. Since it isn't stored into a variable either this script is pretty useless. The .text(variable).html() part also doesn't make sense: It sets the contents of the div to an empty string and than returns the contents of the div.

Comment: Yeah, then we can say that the div is used as any HTML tag just to get the contents of it. Right? If I am right, then that was what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't make sense to create elements when you're not adding them to the page. Why not using javascript variables or objects instead? And then again, in this script the element isn't stored into a variable so it will probably be destroyed right after it is created.

Comment: That is what I am thinking. As I said, that code block is a part of an example I was looking at (SignalR chathub example). That's why I was confused. Thanks for clearifying that for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's not a selector.

It's turning a string into a jQuery element.

It's the same was writing `$('<div></div>')` except it's shorter.

Comment: I just added an edit note. When the code runs it doesn't show any divs either. Let me write the rest of the code. Just a min.

Comment: Why would it *show* anything? It is creating a div. Setting it's text value to something. Fetching it's html value. Then doing nothing with it.

Comment: What is the logic of creating a div and setting it's text value and getting the html, when you just could use the variable as a text value in li tags? I repeat, the rendered code doesn't show any divs, it's just text in li tags.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is not a selector, but it's instead creating an HTML element on the fly that is not part of the current document.

However - nobody's yet explained what it's actually doing.

The purpose of setting the text value and then getting the HTML value of an in-memory `<div>` is to html-encode a string of text. This doesn't make a lot of sense in your original question, which is using an empty string, but consider the following example:

```
var variable = 'This & That < 5'; // a text value with special characters

var x = $('<div />'); // creates an ad-hoc div element in memory

x.text(variable); // sets the text contained within the DIV
                  // to 'This & That < 5'. This is the actual literal
                  // text that would be displayed if the element was
                  // displayed in a browser.

var encoded = x.html(); // gets the HTML representation of
                        // the contents of the div

alert(encoded); // shows "This &amp; That &lt; 5"
```

Now that you understand what's happening though, I should point out that building an HTML string like that is **NOT** the best way to approach this problem. Instead, it makes more sense to build the elements you actually need, like this:

```
// a name and message from somewhere - you don't show where
// these values from in your code above.
var name = "Bob O'Conner";
var message = "Hi, welcome to my <website>.";

var newItem = $('<li />').text(':' + message);
var newTitle = $('<strong />').text(name);
newItem.prepend(newTitle);
$('#discussion').append(newItem);
```

Or a shorter version, like this:

```
$('#discussion').append(
    $('<li />').text(':' + message).prepend($('<strong />').text(name))
);
```